# Creating Android 2.2 on Eclipse Neon

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo, eclipse-neon

I'm trying to create a new project with Android 2.2 (Froyo) but it seems that it's not working! I'm using Eclipse Neon on Mac, it says "This template requires a build target API version of at least 14, and the current version is 8"

I added two pictures

[image: Here]

and

[image: Here]

Comment: Eclipse neon is the latest Eclipse version and you are trying to make it work with the old outdated Android development tools for Eclipse? Guess what is wrong here. Have you tried an older version of Eclipse? Anyway AFAIR the API bundles for API8 are no longer available at Google. You have to get it somewhere else and integrate it into Android SDK.

Comment: Hello Robert, I imported an old project and it was fine!

Comment: Do you recommend any older Eclipse that works with\ mac?